# Code executing two times in firebase onDatachange when button clicked once

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am updating data in my firebase realtime database using firebase onDataChange with the codes below when a user clicks a button. All the codes in the onDataChange method executes once when there is a button click but the codes numbered #1 one the 'intent activity' executes twice even though i click the button once. What might be the problem?

```
     if (dataSnapshot.child(uid2).hasChild(postID2)) 
{

                                                    //Create matches node
       databaseReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    if (dataSnapshot.child("Male").hasChild(postUser_id)) {
                                                              //  view.setEnabled(false);
              databaseReference2.child(user_id).child(postUser_id).setValue(username2);

              databaseReference3.child(user_id).child(postUser_id).setValue(username2);

            databaseReference5.child(uid1).child(user_id).setValue(new Match1(username1,currentUser_username2,postpicf,user_id));
      databaseReference5.child(user_id).child(uid1).setValue(new Match1(username2,currentUser_username1,postpicm,uid1));

    //#6 databaseReference6.child(uid1).push().setValue("New Friendc");



        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MatchView.class);
        profileIntent.putExtra("postID", postUser_id);
        startActivity(profileIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description of the processing, you want to [read the data once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once) and should use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead of `addValueEventListener()`, which leaves the listener attached.  Executing the code you posted multiple times results in multiple active listeners, with `onDataChange()` firing multiple times when the data changes.

```
databaseReference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        ...
    }
});
```